# How to get the full file path of a Box File given file ID using the API

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to fetch the complete folder path of a file given the file Id using the Box API?

From the API documentation it is clear that we can use the Parent Folder ID to recursively fetch folder names until the root is reached, however this would result in a lot of REST API calls depending on the number of parent folders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `path_collection` property of the `file` object contains "*the path of folders to this item, starting at the root.*" This information can be fetched in a single API request using only the file ID. See the [documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-get) for a detailed example, a portion of which is shown below. The `total_count` field indicates the depth of the tree for that file, and the `entries` field contains information about each folder in the tree.  It's my understanding that the `entries` are returned in order.

```
 "path_collection": {
    "total_count": 2,
    "entries": [
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "id": "0",
            "sequence_id": null,
            "etag": null,
            "name": "All Files"
        },
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "id": "11446498",
            "sequence_id": "1",
            "etag": "1",
            "name": "Pictures"
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   private String getFullPath(BoxFile.Info info)
   {
      List<BoxFolder> filePathList = info.getPathCollection();
      StringBuffer fullPathStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
      for (BoxFolder pf : filePathList)
      {
         fullPathStringBuffer.append("/").append(pf.getInfo().getName());
      }
      System.out.println(fullPathStringBuffer.toString());
      return fullPathStringBuffer.toString();
   }
```